# Magento Conditional Configurable Products

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, configurable-product

I am new to magento and wanted to know if I can create products using conditional logic? For example the countries and states dropdowns.

Users choose the country and based on that a state dropdown is populated. I will also have a dropdown for mobile phone models and prices differ for each of them. Prices will be based on country, state and phone model.

Using only configurable products in Magento I am not able to achieve this as I cannot populate the state dropdown based on countries.

How can I be able to achieve this in Magento? If not is there any extension that I can use to achieve this country and state configurable dropdowns?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

yes and no.

there are simple products assigned to a configurable product. After selecting the first dropdown, the next appears. If a simple product with a certain mix of attributes is available, it is mapped to the dropdown if not, then not.

For example:

```
Shirts
 - blue, L
 - blue, M
 - blue, S
 - red, M
 - red, L
```

and you select blue, the size dropdown shows L, M and S. If you select red you can only choose between M and L.

You can only define price differences. If you want an easier way to define the prices use BCP - Better Configurable Products: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/better-configurable-products.html